# How do I programmatically determine if there are uncommitted changes?

Tags: git

In a Makefile, I'd like to perform certain actions if there are uncommitted changes (either in the working tree or the index).  What's the cleanest and most efficient way to do that?  A command that exits with a return value of zero in one case and non-zero in the other would suit my purposes.

I can run `git status` and pipe the output through `grep`, but I feel like there must be a better way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking for a dirty index or untracked files with Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657935/checking-for-a-dirty-index-or-untracked-files-with-git)

Comment: There's a great answer here: [Unix & Llinux: Determine if Git working directory is clean from a script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/155077/114401)

Answer (score 382, accepted):

**UPDATES**:

- [trusktr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/454780/trusktr) mentions in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878624/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-if-there-are-uncommitted-changes/3879077#comment136425825_3878934) of [Josh Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19750/josh-lee)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3878934/6309)

  > Other methods using porcelain assume you're in bash, and that's not cross-shell or cross-platform compatible.
  > This one works everywhere:
  >
  > ```
  > git add . && git diff --quiet && git diff --cached --quiet
  > ```
  >
  > seems like it catches every case I need (including untracked files, and git submodules with unstaged modifications which `git add .` will not stage)
- the OP [Daniel Stutzbach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219162/daniel-stutzbach) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878624/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-if-there-are-uncommited-changes/41646552#comment4133162_3879077) that this simple command [`git diff-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-index) worked for him:

  ```
  git update-index --refresh 
  git diff-index --quiet HEAD --
  ```

A more precise option would be to test `git status --porcelain=v1 2>/dev/null | wc -l`, using the [`porcelain` option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6978402/6309).
See [Myridium](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1351182/myridium)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62768943/6309).

([nornagon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216728/nornagon) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878624/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-if-there-are-uncommitted-changes/3879077#comment108071431_3879077) that, if there are files that have been touched, but whose contents are the same as in the index, you'll need to run `git update-index --refresh` before `git diff-index`, otherwise `diff-index` will incorrectly report that the tree is dirty)

You can then see "[How to check if a command succeeded?](https://askubuntu.com/q/29370/5470)" if you are using it in a bash script:

```
git diff-index --quiet HEAD -- || echo "untracked"; // do something about it
```

Note: as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878624/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-if-there-are-uncommited-changes/3879077#comment77799000_3879077) by [Anthony Sottile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812183/anthony-sottile)

> `git diff-index HEAD ...` will fail on a branch which has no commits (such as a newly initialized repository).
> One workaround I've found is `git diff-index $(git write-tree) ...`

And [`haridsv`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95750/haridsv) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878624/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-if-there-are-uncommitted-changes/3879077#comment99931004_3879077) that `git diff-files` on a *new* file doesn't detect it as a diff.
The safer approach seems to be to run `git add` on the file spec first and then use `git diff-index` to see if anything got added to index before running `git commit`.

> ```
> git add ${file_args} && \
> git diff-index --cached --quiet HEAD || git commit -m '${commit_msg}'
> ```

And [6502](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320726/6502) reports in the comments:

> One problem I bumped in is that `git diff-index` will tell that there are differences when indeed there is none except for timestamps of the files.
> Running `git diff` once solves the issue (surprisingly enough, `git diff` does actually change the content of the sandbox, meaning here `.git/index`)

These timestamp issues can also occur if git is [running in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49185186/fix-git-diff-files-listing-all-files-in-docker).

---

Original answer:

"Programmatically" means **never ever rely on [porcelain commands](http://schacon.github.io/git/git.html#_high_level_commands_porcelain)**.
**Always rely on [plumbing commands](http://schacon.github.io/git/git.html#_low_level_commands_plumbing)**.

See also "[Checking for a dirty index or untracked files with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657935/checking-for-a-dirty-index-or-untracked-files-with-git)" for alternatives (like `git status --porcelain`)

You can take inspiration [from the new "**`require_clean_work_tree` function**" which is written as we speak](http://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg142043.html) ;) (early October 2010)

```
require_clean_work_tree () {
    # Update the index
    git update-index -q --ignore-submodules --refresh
    err=0

    # Disallow unstaged changes in the working tree
    if ! git diff-files --quiet --ignore-submodules --
    then
        echo >&2 "cannot $1: you have unstaged changes."
        git diff-files --name-status -r --ignore-submodules -- >&2
        err=1
    fi

    # Disallow uncommitted changes in the index
    if ! git diff-index --cached --quiet HEAD --ignore-submodules --
    then
        echo >&2 "cannot $1: your index contains uncommitted changes."
        git diff-index --cached --name-status -r --ignore-submodules HEAD -- >&2
        err=1
    fi

    if [ $err = 1 ]
    then
        echo >&2 "Please commit or stash them."
        exit 1
    fi
}
```

Comment: The "plumbing vs. porcelain for scripting" principle is a lesson that [Jakub Narębski](http://stackoverflow.com/users/46058/jakub-narebski) repeatedly mentioned to me: " [How to list all the log for current project in git ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978947/how-to-list-all-the-log-for-current-project-in-git/2979124#2979124) ", " [git: changelog day by day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976665/git-changelog-day-by-day/2976776#2976776) ", ...

Comment: After clicking some of the links you suggest, I found what I was looking for: `git diff-index --quiet HEAD`.

Comment: @DanielStutzbach: That might fail if you have a file called `HEAD` in the working directory. Better use `git diff-index --quiet HEAD --`.

Comment: New (untracked) files are not detected by proposed function require_clean_work_tree.
I needed to detect any change (even forgotten new files), so I chose Nepthar's answer:
`[[ -z $(git status -s) ]]`

Comment: @4LegsDrivenCat OK. Do you have an example which illustrates that issue? On which platform do you see this? What version of Git are you using?

Comment: git version 1.9.1.
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.
To reproduce, just create new file.

Comment: @4LegsDrivenCat OK. I just realized I wrote that answer 5 years ago. It was Git 1.7.3 back then.

Comment: @4LegsDrivenCat Do you have any suggestion to fix the function in order to detect new untracked files?

Comment: @VonC No. As I said, checking for empty output of "git status --short" worked for me (detects staged, modified and new files), so I didn't dig deeper.

Comment: And yet the manual at `git status --help` states:
       **--porcelain**
_Give the output in an easy-to-parse format for scripts. This is similar to the short output, but will remain stable across Git versions and regardless of  user configuration. See below for details._

Comment: @EdRandall You're right, the git documentation seems to contradict itself! I guess relying on the output format of `git status --porcelain` in a script isn't so bad after all.

Comment: @theDmi Actually it makes sense: "the meaning of --porcelain here is "produce output suitable for consumption by porcelain scripts". See the end of my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6978402/6309. So yes, `git status --porcelain` is good for scripting.

Comment: @VonC that really makes no sense. This way you can twist everything into its reverse. --porcelain gives you the impression it is going to break soon. If it isn't, it should be called plumbing, not porcelain. Using --porcelain causes your script not to break, which renders it NOT a porcelain script ;-). If you wanted your script to break, you shouldn't use --porcelain!!. So it completely incomprehensible this and throws everyone off.

Comment: @VonC but usually these flags are just called --script or something similar. Because of this I consider --porcelain a flag that could easily change in the future ;-).

Comment: @Xennex81 I agree. This is named that way for historical reason (2010) See http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-status-porcelain-is-a-mess-that-needs-fixing-tp4878858p4880785.html (look for "this is my fault")

Comment: @VonC actually that seemed to have been only about the command. Or the format. The main criticism is not the name, but that it is not even easy to script with. And hard to understand. I think even --plumbing would be bad nomenclature. Scripting with only plumbing commands is practically impossible as well. That's like having to repeat everything these commands do. What's the point of that. I find it hard to come up with commands that do have a --script option though. They seem to be few out there.

Comment: @Xennex81 Interesting. If you have an example in mind which is difficult to script, don't hesitate to post a question here on Stack Overflow. That way, other Git specialists will have a chance to comment on it, and others to learn from it.

Comment: @VonC no no, the post you referenced was full of criticism on the format, saying it was incomprehensible to someone who wasn't its actual developer. There was even talk of a --porcelain=v2, and how incredulous that would be.

Comment: Note that `git diff-index HEAD ...` will fail on a branch which has no commits (such as a newly initialized repository).  One workaround I've found is `git diff-index $(git write-tree) ...`

Comment: @AnthonySottile Thank you, very good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Well, `git diff-index --quiet HEAD --` doesn't take into account new untracked files.
So better to use `git status` but with [`--porcelain`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6978402/350384) parameter as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5737794/350384)

Comment: I had a `diff-files` based utility function that took a file spec and did a commit conditionally and this didn't work when a new file needed to be committed, as `git diff-files` on a new file doesn't detect it as a diff. The safer approach seems to be to run `git add` on the file spec first and then use `git diff-index` to see if anything got added to index before running `git commit`.

Comment: @haridsv Interesting. Do you have a script or an alias using that approach?

Comment: @VonC It goes something like this: `git add ${file_args} && git diff-index --cached --quiet HEAD || git commit -m '${commit_msg}'`.

Comment: @haridsv Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I have a totally clean `branch` nothing to commit. This command fails then then, I need to actually `push` first. Usually that worked but now even after a push it fails for me and I do not know why.

Comment: @redanimalwar Strange. A separate question with a way to reproduce the issue would be ideal here.

Comment: One problem I bumped in is that `git diff-index` will tell that there are differences when indeed there is none except for timestamps of the files. Running `git diff` once solves the issue (surprisingly enough `git diff` does actually change the content of the sandbox)

Comment: @6502 Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. What is your OS and Git version? (to understand why a `git diff` would modify timestamp)

Comment: @VonC: I'm using git version 2.23.0 on arch linux

Comment: @6502 OK. May be there a smudge/clean content filter script active, or simply a `git config core.autocrlf` which may attempt to modify the content of the working tree file.

Comment: @VonC: `git diff` doesn't change the file timestamps, but it changes something inside `.git/index` that makes `git diff-index HEAD` not reporting the file any more.

Comment: @6502 OK, got it (I have edited the answer accordingly)

Comment: if `--quiet` always nothing. usless

Comment: Note that if there are files that have been touched but whose contents are the same as in the index, you'll need to run `git update-index --refresh` before `git diff-index`, otherwise `diff-index` will incorrectly report that the tree is dirty.

Comment: @nornagon Thank you, good catch. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Answer does not detect untracked files.

Answer (score 173):

While the other solutions are very thorough, if you want something really quick and dirty, try something like this:

```bash
[[ -z "$(git status -s)" ]]
```

It just checks if there is any output in the status summary.

Comment: works for me. use -n for the inverse (you have changes) e.g.
`
if [[ -n $(git status -s) ]]; then ... fi`

Comment: This works, but can you tell what the `[[ ... ]]` syntax is actually doing? I've never seen anything like that before.

Comment: [[ is a shell keyword (`$ type [[`) in bash and most shells. It behaves like the `test` command. You'll often see it as part of an if statement: `if [[ -f "$my_file" ]]; then echo "found!"; else echo "not found; fi`

Comment: `git status` returns exit code 0 for me, whether there are changes or not. git 2.6.3 on Windows.

Comment: @EM the return code of `git status` is actually ignored in this test. It only looks at the output. Check out [this bash related page](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest#string_tests) for more info on `[`, `[[` and how testing works in bash.

Comment: Oh, yes, of course - thanks! I was trying to replicate this on Windows.

Comment: [difference between test, [ and [[](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)

Comment: This is almost right answer, but for script it's better to use [`--porcelain`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6978402/350384) parameter as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5737794/350384)

Comment: You might want to use `git status -s -uall` to include untracked files.

Comment: @barfuin it looks like `git status` defaults to `all`.  From `git status -h`:

`-u, --untracked-files[=<mode>]`

`show untracked files, optional modes: all, normal, no. (Default: all)`

Comment: [ -z "$(git status -s)" ] -- posix & quoted

Answer (score 83):

`git diff --exit-code` will return nonzero if there are any changes; `git diff --quiet` is the same with no output. Since you want to check for the working tree and the index, use

```
git diff --quiet && git diff --cached --quiet
```

Or

```
git diff --quiet HEAD
```

Either one will tell you if there are uncommitted changes that are staged or not.

If you want to include untracked files in the test, use `git add` to stag them first:

```
git add . && git diff --quiet && git diff --cached --quiet
```

The `git diff --cached --quiet` command will catch untracked files that have now been staged with `git add .`. The `git diff --quiet` command is still nneeded for catching git submodules with unstaged changes, as `git add .` will not stage git submodules that have modifications.

When you need to run this check in a cross-platform way, this method is better than most other answers because other answers parse outputs of various other commands (namely `git status --porcelain`) in a shell-specific way, which means those methods will not work cross-platform. For example, they won't work in Windows PowerShell.

Relying on exit codes will work in a cross-platform way, so the above command using `&&` works pretty much everywhere in macOS, Linux, and Windows. This can be especially useful, for example, for cross-platform NPM scripts in `package.json` files of JavaScript projects.

Comment: Those are not equivalent. The single command `git diff --quite HEAD` will only tell you whether the working tree is clean, not whether the index is clean. For example, if `file` was changed between HEAD~ and HEAD, then after `git reset HEAD~ -- file`, it will still exit 0 even though there are staged changes present in the index (wt == HEAD, but index != HEAD).

Comment: Warning, this will not catch files removed from the staging area with git rm, AFAICS.

Comment: New (untracked) files are not detected by `git diff --quiet && git diff --cached --quiet` .

Comment: @4LegsDrivenCat how about `git add . && git diff --cached --quiet`?

Comment: @nmr how about `git add . && git diff --cached --quiet`?

Comment: This is great! Other methods using porcelain assume you're in bash, and that's not cross-shell or cross-platform compatible. This one works everywhere. In particular, `git add . && git diff --quiet && git diff --cached --quiet` seems like it catches every case I need (including untracked files, and git submodules with unstaged modifications which `git add .` will not stage). Is there a case it doesn't catch?

Answer (score 34):

Expanding on [@Nepthar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9393642):

```
if [[ -z $(git status -s) ]]
then
  echo "tree is clean"
else
  echo "tree is dirty, please commit changes before running this"
  exit
fi
```

Comment: This is good; I use it to autocommit single files by testing `$(git status -s "$file")` and then in the `else` clause `git add "$file"; git commit -m "your autocommit process" "$file"`

Comment: If you make that `git status -s` an `git status --porcelain ; git clean -nd` instead, junk directories will be surfaced here too, which are invisible to `git status`.

Answer (score 32):

Some answers are overcomplicating the matter or not achieving the desired result. E.g. the accepted answer misses untracked files.

You can use `git status --porcelain=v1` and parse the output programatically. The output is empty if there is some uncommitted change, otherwise it is not empty.

A POSIX-compliant minimum working example:

```bash
[ -z "$(git status --porcelain=v1 2>/dev/null)" ] && echo "No uncommitted changes."
```

If run outside a git repository, this will still say `No uncommitted changes`.

### Details

- The option `--porcelain` gives a machine-parseable output.
- The option specification `--porcelain=v1` fixes the output version of the machine-parseable output, so that your script will never break under a future `git` update. As of my writing, you can check https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status for information about other version options, like `--porcelain=v2`. You may be able to do more advanced scripting with versions beyond `v1`.
- The `2>/dev/null` is there so that `git status` will fail silently, if at all (i.e., if run outside of a git repository).
- As of this writing, the command `git status ...` will return exit code `128` if it is not inside a git repository. You can check explicitly for this exit code if you want a third option besides "uncommitted changes" or "no uncommitted changes".

---

### Extra: counting dirty files

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2658301/1351182). You `grep` the lines of `git status --porcelain=v1` output. The first two characters of each line indicate what the status is of the particular file. After grepping, you count how many have that status by piping the output to `wc -l` which counts the number of lines.

You may code up some more advanced behaviour this way, or pick and choose what you consider qualifies as "uncommitted changes".

E.g. this script will print some information if run inside a git repository.

```bash
#!/bin/sh
GS=$(git status --porcelain=v1 2>/dev/null) # Exit code 128 if not in git directory. Unfortunately this exit code is a bit generic but it should work for most purposes.
if [ $? -ne 128 ]; then
  function _count_git_pattern() {
    echo "$(grep "^$1" <<< $GS | wc -l)" 
  }                                           
  echo "There are $(_count_git_pattern "??") untracked files."                                 
  echo "There are $(_count_git_pattern " M") unstaged, modified files."
  echo "There are $(_count_git_pattern "M ")   staged, modified files."        
fi
```

Comment: @VonC - indeed, I checked the documentation https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status and noticed the version option. There's a v2 already but it's not default. Also I know other people have already quoted this elsewhere in the comments, but it says of the `--porcelain` option: *"Give the output in an easy-to-parse format for scripts. This is similar to the short output, but will remain stable across Git versions and regardless of user configuration."*

Comment: Yes, v2 has been introduced in Git 2.11 (https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9fc746cd77910a7dec53abfec36df5c699b33c2), aug. 2016.

Comment: I keep getting `zsh: command not found: M` in MacOS terminal?

Comment: @ChuckLeButt I've tested with `zsh` on MacOS and it works okay for me. What are you putting into the terminal exactly?

Comment: This gives me the incorrect number of untracked files!

Comment: @jtlz2 - Could you please share the output of `git status --porcelain=v1 2>/dev/null`? You can remove sensitive information.

Answer (score 10):

The working tree is "clean" if

```bash
git ls-files \
  --deleted \
  --modified \
  --others \
  --exclude-standard \
  -- :/
```

returns nothing.

## Explanation

- `--deleted` check for files deleted in the working tree
- `--modified` check for files modified in the working tree
- `--others` check for files added in the working tree
- `--exclude-standard` ignore according to the usual `.gitignore`, `.git/info/exclude` ... rules
- `-- :/` pathspec for everything, needed if not running in the root of the repository

That output is empty if the working tree is clean

Comment: It does not see new directories in the working tree

Comment: @ESkri that's because git doesn't track directories, it only ever tracks files. Empty directories do not exist as far as Git is concerned

Comment: Yes, there are no empty directories in the repo (for example, it is impossible to add empty directory to the index).  But git does know about empty directories in the working tree.  For example, git successfully deletes them with `git clean -d`.

Comment: The working tree is not clean if `git clean` has something to do in it.  Pun intended.

Comment: For finding uncommited changes, `git ls-files` does the job. Sure, you could `git clean -dn -- :/ | grep '.' || echo clean` but it's not a plumbing command.

Comment: I appreciated the readability of this answer, but couldn't adapt it to check for staged files in my particular case. :(

Comment: @combinatorist maybe I missed an edge case. what didn't work in your case?

Comment: @CervEd, I had a slightly different need (to show staged diffs), so I just did `git diff --staged | wc -l` instead.

Comment: @combinatorist you're probably looking for `git diff-index --cached --quiet HEAD -- && true || false`

Comment: Ok, thank you for that alternative, but as will everything in the git syntax, I don't see why that's not just an argument to the ls-files argument. In git's (terrible) UI, everything is possible from any given command ... except of course  that one thing, which forces you to consider a dozen other commands instead. Lol.

When I read your comment, I thought `ls-files` would an unusually clear and flexible git command. I'm not blaming you that it's not - just complaining about git's (lack of) design.

Answer (score 8):

I created some handy git aliases to list unstaged and staged files:

```
git config --global alias.unstaged 'diff --name-only'
git config --global alias.staged 'diff --name-only --cached'
```

Then you can easily do things like:

```
[[ -n "$(git unstaged)" ]] && echo unstaged files || echo NO unstaged files
[[ -n "$(git staged)" ]] && echo staged files || echo NO staged files
```

---

You can make it more readable by creating a script somewhere on your `PATH` called `git-has`:

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ $(git "$@" | wc -c) -ne 0 ]]
```

Now the above examples can be simplified to:

```
git has unstaged && echo unstaged files || echo NO unstaged files
git has staged && echo staged files || echo NO staged files
```

---

For completeness here are similar aliases for untracked and ignored files:

```
git config --global alias.untracked 'ls-files --exclude-standard --others'
git config --global alias.ignored 'ls-files --exclude-standard --others --ignored'
```

Answer (score 6):

With python and the GitPython package:

```py
import git
git.Repo(path).is_dirty(untracked_files=True)
```

Returns `True` if repository is not clean

Comment: This avoided some of the "timestamp" issues mentioned in other comments

Comment: Note that GitPython is just using the git CLI as well. If you set `LOGLEVEL=DEBUG` you will see all the Popen commands it it using to run `git diff`

Comment: Assuming the package is well tested, it is more reliable to let package maintainers keep the functions working properly if/when Git changes. GitPython's docs indicate that it may leak resources and that causes me concern.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed in other answer, as simple as such command is sufficient:

```
git diff-index --quiet HEAD --
```

If you omit the last two dashes, the command would fail if you have a file named `HEAD`.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
echo -n "Checking if there are uncommited changes... "
trap 'echo -e "\033[0;31mFAILED\033[0m"' ERR
git diff-index --quiet HEAD --
trap - ERR
echo -e "\033[0;32mAll set!\033[0m"

# continue as planned...
```

Word of caution: this command ignores untracked files.

Comment: As pointed in comments to that answer, this doesn't detect newly added files

Comment: No, it does detect newly added to index files. Just checked.

Comment: See question. Untracked files are not *changes*. `git add` and `git clean` to the rescue

Answer (score 1):

*Tested in the bash terminal on Linux Ubuntu.*

### Shell script to programmatically interpret the output of `git status`

...and tell you if:

1. it had an error
2. it shows your working tree is clean (no uncommitted changes), or
3. it shows your working tree is dirty (you have uncommited changes).

There's a great answer here: [Unix & Llinux: Determine if Git working directory is clean from a script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/155077/114401). My answer is based on that.

We will use the `--porcelain` option with `git status` because it is intended to be parsed by scripts!

From `man git status` (emphasis added):

> `--porcelain[=<version>]`
>
> Give the output in an **easy-to-parse format for scripts**. This is similar to the short output, but **will remain stable across Git versions and regardless of user configuration.** See below for details.
>
> The `version` parameter is used to specify the format version. This is optional and defaults to the original version v1 format.

So, do this:

#### Option 1

```bash
if output="$(git status --porcelain)" && [ -z "$output" ]; then
    echo "'git status --porcelain' had no errors AND the working directory" \
         "is clean."
else 
    echo "Working directory has UNCOMMITTED CHANGES."
fi
```

The first part, `if output=$(git status --porcelain)` will fail and jump to the `else` clause if the `git status --porcelain` command has an error. the 2nd part, `&& [ -z "$output" ]`, tests to see if the `output` variable contains an empty (`z`ero-length) string. If it does, then the `git status` is clean and there are no changes.

#### Option 2

**Generally my preferred usage**, however, is to negate the test with `-n` (nonzero) instead of `-z` (zero) and do it like this:

```bash
if output="$(git status --porcelain)" && [ -n "$output" ]; then
    echo "'git status --porcelain' had no errors AND the working directory" \
         "is dirty (has UNCOMMITTED changes)."
    # Commit the changes here
    git add -A
    git commit -m "AUTOMATICALLY COMMITTING UNCOMMITTED CHANGES"
fi
```

#### Option 3

A more-granular way to write the first code block above would be like this:

```bash
if ! git_status_output="$(git status --porcelain)"; then
    # `git status` had an error
    error_code="$?"
    echo "'git status' had an error: $error_code" 
    # exit 1  # (optional)
elif [ -z "$git_status_output" ]; then
    # Working directory is clean
    echo "Working directory is clean."
else
    # Working directory has uncommitted changes.
    echo "Working directory has UNCOMMITTED CHANGES."
    # exit 2  # (optional)
fi
```

I've tested all of the above code by copying and pasting the whole blocks into my terminal in a repo in varying states, and it works fine for all 3 conditions:

1. your `git status` command is wrong or misspelled
2. `git status` is clean (no uncommitted changes)
3. `git status` is dirty (you have uncommitted changes)

To force the `'git status' had an error` output, simply misspell the `--porcelain` option by spelling it as `--porcelainn` or something, and you'll see this output at the very end:

> ```
> 'git status' had an error: 0
> ```

### See also

1. My answer here: [Get the hash for the current commit, *and* see if `git status` is "clean" or "dirty"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76856090/4561887)

Answer (score -3):

Here is the best, cleanest way.

```
function git_dirty {
    text=$(git status)
    changed_text="Changes to be committed"
    untracked_files="Untracked files"

    dirty=false

    if [[ ${text} = *"$changed_text"* ]];then
        dirty=true
    fi

    if [[ ${text} = *"$untracked_files"* ]];then
        dirty=true
    fi

    echo $dirty
}
```

Comment: No, this is not the best. `git status` is a 'porcelain' command. Don't use porcelain commands in scripts since they can change between git versions. Instead use 'plumbing' commands.

Comment: I think if you updated it to use `git status --porcelain` (which is meant for this purpose--a stable format you can parse in a script), possibly also with -z (null-separated instead of newline?) you could do something useful with this idea. @codyc4321  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976473/what-does-the-term-porcelain-mean-in-git for details