# What's an easy way to detect modified files in a Git workspace?

Tags: git, build-process, makefile

During make, I create string fields which I embedded in the linked output.  Very useful.

Other than a complex `sed`/`grep` parsing of the `git status` command, how can I easily determine if files in the workspace have been modified according to `git`?

Comment: If you are only care to know whether something has changed (not which ones have changed) see [How do I programmatically determine if there are uncommited changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3878624/193688)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

If you just want a plain “Are there any differences from HEAD?”:

```
git diff-index --quiet HEAD
```

If the exit code is 0, then there were no differences.

If you want “What files have changed from HEAD?”:

```
git diff-index --name-only HEAD
```

If you want “What files have changed from HEAD, and in what ways have they changed (added, deleted, changed)?”:

```
git diff-index --name-status HEAD
```

Add `-M` (and `-C`) if you want rename (and copy) detection.

These commands will check both the staged contents (what is in the index) and the files in the working tree. Alternatives like `git ls-files -m` will only check the working tree against the index (i.e. they will disregard any staged (but uncommitted) content that is also in the working tree).

Comment: @Jamie This answer should probably be selected as the correct answer.

Comment: There’s definitely an edge case where this currently doesn’t work correctly; any idea how to solve it? If you merely `touch` a file, then immediately run `git diff-index HEAD`, that detects the touched file as changed! There seems to be some sort of cache that commands like `git status` first updates, but that `git diff-index` does not. The `git-diff-index` man page says, “The all-zero sha1 means that to get the real diff, you need to look at the object in the working directory directly rather than do an object-to-object diff.” Is there a command that can do that?

Comment: @andrewdotn Try `git update-index -q --refresh` before *diff-index*. It should update the cached ctime/mtime that is causing the false positive.

Comment: @ChrisJohnsen Thanks. I had a similar problem to andrewdotn's (on files removed then restored by MPFR's autogen.sh), and `git update-index -q --refresh` avoids it (just like `git status`). But I wonder about the meaning of "Looks at the current index and checks to see if merges or updates are needed by checking stat() information." in the git-update-index(1) man page.

Comment: Due to the quirks @andrewdotn and @ChrisJohnsen mentioned, I switched to using `git status --porcelain`, see the other answer below, which seems to work much better.

Answer (score 45):

From `git help -a`:

```
git ls-files -m
```

Comment: @Jamie: Files with staged (but uncommitted) changes will not show up with `git ls-files -m`, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Ah.  Thanks for your input.  Truthfully, `git ls-files -m` isn't what I want, but it does answer my specific question.  +1 for comment and answer though.

Comment: Unfortunately with a contemporary version of Git [2.10.1 (Apple Git-78)] this doesn't appear to work.

Comment: @Mark I have `git version 2.11.0`, and it works here.

Answer (score 29):

`git status --porcelain` seems to give a nice parsable output.

Comment: Very nice. Will be useful for other reasons.

Comment: That's great, I just used it to automate git commit summaries (like you get from GitHub's web interface) which I actually came to this question looking for: [one-liner to add, commit and push](https://github.com/lmmx/devnotes/wiki/Automated-git-status-summary).

Answer (score 6):

For git hooks, I found this command useful

```
git diff-index --exit-code --ignore-submodules HEAD
```

For example

```
//run some static analysis check that can change the code
something_changed=`git diff-index --exit-code --ignore-submodules HEAD`
if [ -n "$something_changed" ]
then
    echo >&2 "Something changed in $local_ref, not pushing"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: I like this because it fails the command if there is a change. I am using it on a file that shouldn't change in CI.

Answer (score 5):

`git diff --name-only` does the same (might be more intuitive...)

Answer (score 0):

An approach with fewer sharp corners:

```
git diff --quiet HEAD
```

This appears to do the same thing as the `diff-index` answer, but with an advantage: it rebuilds the index if necessary, eliminating some flakiness of `diff-index`.  Additionally, `diff` works correctly when the repository isn't writable by apparently building a temporary index (while `diff-index`, if the index is stale, will say everything is modified, and the index can't be updated to fix that).