# How do I use rugged to check if there are uncommited changes in my git repository?

Tags: ruby, libgit2, rugged

How do I use [rugged](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged) to check whether there are uncommitted changes in my git repo?

Much like [How do I programmatically determine if there are uncommited changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878624/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-if-there-are-uncommited-changes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow. This question has been dead from some time, but thought I'd throw in my 2 cents as I'm using learning/using `Rugged` currently.

There's a handy method [`Repository#diff_workdir`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/libgit2/rugged/Rugged/Repository#diff_workdir-instance_method) that exists nowadays.

Suppose you want to compare the working directory to the last commit( the equivalent of what I think of just a plain old `git diff`). You can get that with this:

```
repo.diff_workdir(repo.last_commit)
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

You do it the same way. Either ask status or diff whether there are changes between HEAD and the worktree.

Rugged doesn't have diff support merged in yet, so you'd have to use status.

Answer (score 0):

Diff support was recently added. You can pull the latest version from github.

```
a = Rugged::Tree.lookup(repo, "806999").tree
b = Rugged::Tree.lookup(repo, "a8595c").tree

diff = a.diff(b)

deltas = diff.deltas
patches = diff.patches
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get something similar to `git status` using [`Repository#status`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/libgit2/rugged/Rugged%2FRepository%3Astatus).

If you'd just like to check if there are any unstaged changes:

```
repository.to_enum(:status).any?
```