# git diff and bash return code

Tags: git, bash

I am trying to find out whether a local git repo has some staged change.

I run the below command, however, bash gave different return code (the * indicates there is staged change

```
db 14:59:06 ~/pg/services/
(master) * [origin ] $ bash -c 'git diff --staged --quiet -- code/ || echo $?'
1
db 14:59:13 ~/pg/services/
(master) * [origin ] $  git diff --staged --quiet -- code/
db 14:59:32 ~/pg/services/
(master) * [origin ] $ echo $?  
0
```

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3879077/2295034

Comment: One command uses `--staged`, the other doesn't. That could make a big difference.

Comment: @chepner yeah. I used --staged as well and the return code is the same. fixed the commands