# bash diff return 0 when with 'sh -c'

Tags: bash

I was trying to diff some files, and do something if is different.
But when combining with sh -c, diff can not return proper exit code.

```
root@i-qqixe8m2:~# cat /tmp/1
1
root@i-qqixe8m2:~# cat /tmp/2
2
root@i-qqixe8m2:~# set +x # Edited: useless cmd. But still kept here since answer below by @iBug would refer to this.
root@i-qqixe8m2:~# sh -c "diff /tmp/1 /tmp/2; echo $?;"
1c1
< 1
---
> 2
0
root@i-qqixe8m2:~# diff /tmp/1 /tmp/2; echo $?;
1c1
< 1
---
> 2
1
root@i-qqixe8m2:~#
```

PS. I found related question here: [git diff and bash return code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43748835/git-diff-and-bash-return-code), but no reason provided, and comments below I believe is not the real right solution, since I don't use git here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using double quotes, `$?` is already expanded by your current shell instead of `sh`:

```
sh -c "diff /tmp/1 /tmp/2; echo $?;"
```

What `sh` sees is that the second command is `echo 0` (the last command `set +x` returns 0).

To fix, use single quotes to prevent `$?` from being expanded by your current shell, so `sh` could handle it properly:

```
sh -c 'diff /tmp/1 /tmp/2; echo $?;'
```

Or maybe just escape the dollar:

```
sh -c "diff /tmp/1 /tmp/2; echo \$?;"
```

It's a good practice to debug shell commands with `set -x`, unsure why you did `+x` instead.

```
~ $ sh -c 'diff 1 2; echo $?;'
+ sh -c 'diff 1 2; echo $?;'
1c1
< 1
---
> 2
1
~ $ sh -c "diff 1 2; echo $?;"
+ sh -c 'diff 1 2; echo 0;'
1c1
< 1
---
> 2
0
~ $
```

Note the two lines starting with a `+`, which is what your shell has actually executed.

Comment: `set +e` here is typo here. Already edit my question here to delete this typo. TKS.