# Check if git status is clean inside a Powershell script

Tags: git, powershell, git-status

I'm developing a Powershell script for create a program release.
In order to do it I want to check if the git working tree is clean and there are no uncommitted changes.

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878624/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-if-there-are-uncommited-changes) but it's related to bash.

How can I check from inside a powershell script if the git working tree is clean and there's anything to commit? I don't care about untracked files.

I've tried something like

```
  $gitOutput = (git status -z) | Out-String
  if ($gitOutput) {
    "output"
  } else {
    "no Output"
  }
```

The problem is that I print `output` also when everything is committed but there are some untracked files, that's something that I'd like to avoid. I want to ignore untracked files and check only if all tracked files are committed.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `git status --porcelain` to get the output as a list that's easy to parse.

Untracked files are prefixed with the status `??`, so you can easily filter those out and then check if there are uncommitted changes based on whether there is any output left:

```
if(git status --porcelain |Where {$_ -match '^\?\?'}){
    # untracked files exist
} 
elseif(git status --porcelain |Where {$_ -notmatch '^\?\?'}) {
    # uncommitted changes
}
else {
    # tree is clean
}
```

Comment: This will filter out any lines that **don't** start ?? which means it will report clean when there are tracked changes pending and only report not clean when there are untracked changes - which is not what was required. The regex should be {$_-match '^[^\?\?]'} this will filter out ?? instead.

Comment: @TheLogicMan Thanks, you're right, updated the answer

Comment: I personally simply do `if (-not (git status --porcelain)) { echo "clean!" }`, or the other way around, `if (git status --porcelain) { throw "not clean!" }`. It works because any value will be truthy (changes detected), and no value will be falsy (no changes detected).

Comment: That is beautiful. Thanks also to Christian for the elegant examples.

Answer (score 10):

I found one another solution using `git status --porcelain`.

```
$ChangedFiles = $(git status --porcelain | Measure-Object | Select-Object -expand Count)
if ($ChangedFiles -gt 0)
{
    Write-Output "Found $ChangedFiles changed files"
}
```

Comment: Best answer: Either it's clean or it's not. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

`git status --porcelain` returns git status in an [stable, easy-to-parse format](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status).

In my own testing, without additional flags it returns specifically an empty string if there are no modifications to tracked files and also no untracked files. To ignore untracked files, the flag `--untracked-files=no` may be added.  The simple powershell statements below leverage that to yield booleans `$hasEditsToTrackedFiles` and `$hasEditsToTrackedFilesOrHasUntrackedFiles`.

Using the `--untracked-files=no` flag seems a little simpler and easier to understand than doing a regex match.  Possibly `--short` could be used here in place of `--porcelain`, but i haven't tested it.

```
$hasEditsToTrackedFiles                    = !([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($(git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no)))
$hasEditsToTrackedFilesOrHasUntrackedFiles = !([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($(git status --porcelain)))
```