# git-diff-files shows modified files after fresh clone

Tags: git

I am attempting to use plumbing commands for the first time and decided to write a script script that will warn me when I've been an idiot and forgotten to commit or push changes.  I'm doing something similar to what is done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3879077/676102).

However, when I make a fresh clone of a repository (`git clone ...`), then run `git diff-files` in that repository, it shows multiple modified files.  If I run `git status`, then re-run `git diff-files`, the modified files are no longer listed.

Since it may matter, I am running on CentOS.

Two questions:

1. What is causing `git diff-files` to think there are modified files
   in a fresh clone?
2. Why does running `git status` "fix" this?

Comment: By fresh clone you mean `git clone ...` or you just copy repository directory?

Comment: I mean `git clone` from a remote repository.