# How to tell whether I have anything to push?

Tags: git

To find out whether I have anything to `pull` I do this:

```
git fetch --dry-run --verbose
```

How can I remind myself whether I have anything to `push`?

Comment: run `git status`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I programmatically determine if there are uncommitted changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878624/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-if-there-are-uncommitted-changes)

Comment: @Obsidian? I'm pretty sure that's not very close

Comment: @Rafael, `git status` doesn't show committed changes that weren't pushed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see uncommitted changes:

```
git status
```

To see uncommitted changes and not pushed commits (works if you have already configured upstream branch):

```
git status --branch
```

To list the not pushed commits:

```
git log @{upstream}..
```

To see the not pushed code:

```
git diff @{u}..
```

Split by commit:

```
git log -p @{u}..
```

And of course

```
git push --dry-run
```

Comment: Thanks, the `git log @{upstream}..` solution was exactly what I wanted.