# List git branches from a single remote

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to list remote git branches from a single remote? The following list branches from all the configured remotes:

```
git branch -r
```

Comment: You may use `git remote show <remote-name>` to see branch information for a specific remote, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471827/how-do-i-list-all-remote-branches-in-git-1-7).  This would also include some other information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `git remote show <remote-name>` it will list all branches existed in that remote

**Example:**
`git remote show origin` or `git remote show https://github.com/test/test-repo.git`

reference : [view docs](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/13/list-remote-branches.html)

Answer (score 2):

Just filter the list

```
git branch -r | grep origin
```

Replace `origin` with desired remote's name.

Comment: This will not work if most of your remote names have *origin*

Comment: Make it `grep \borigin/` then

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to list remote git branches from a single remote?

Git 2.23 (Q3 2019) does update the documentation to answer that very question:

See [commit 1fde99c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1fde99cfc766353237ff1ca4829ba8d71ccebc87) (28 May 2019) by [Philip Oakley (`PhilipOakley`)](https://github.com/PhilipOakley).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ecf55ae](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ecf55ae4f0f73a9759eb58e01cfcc6758acc07c2), 09 Jul 2019)</sup>

> ### doc `branch`: provide examples for listing remote tracking branches
>
> The availability of these pattern selections is not obvious from
>   the man pages.
>
> Provide examples.

The [`git branch` documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1fde99cfc766353237ff1ca4829ba8d71ccebc87/Documentation/git-branch.txt#L325-L336) now has:

> ### Listing branches from a specific remote::
>
> ```
> ------------
> $ git branch -r -l '<remote>/<pattern>'                 <1>
> $ git for-each-ref 'refs/remotes/<remote>/<pattern>'    <2>
> ------------
> ```
>
> - `<1>` Using `-a` would conflate `<remote>` with any local branches you happen to
>     have been prefixed with the same `<remote>` pattern.
> - `<2>` [`for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref) can take a wide range of options.
>
> Patterns will normally need quoting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `rev-parse` instead:

```
 git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic --remotes=<remote-name>
```